# Is it possible to publish items with multiple conditional fields from a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Consider this case, I have a party object, this party object has a few info fields about the party, location, time, guests, etc..
It also has a few fields that set privacy to some of the info fields, like showLocation, showGuests, etc..
These will hide this info from users not invited.

How can I only send to the client the fields where the "show" field is true?

When I publish a single item I can use something like this: (merge is not a real function)

```
Meteor.publish("party", function (_id) {
    var party = Parties.findOne({_id: _id});

    var fields = merge(
        {name: 1, title: 1, creatorUserId: 1},
        (party.showLocationAndDate ? {location: 1, date: 1} : null),
        (party.showGuests ? {guests: 1} : null)
    );

    return Parties.find({_id: _id}, {fields: fields});
});
```

When I publish multiple items but with a single condition I can use something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("parties", function () {
    var fieldsWithLocation = {
        name: 1, 
        title: 1, 
        creatorUserId: 1,
        location: 1
    };
    var fieldsWithoutLocation = {
        name: 1, 
        title: 1, 
        creatorUserId: 1
    };

    //return multiple cursors
    return [
        Parties.find({showLocation: true}, {fields: fieldsWithLocation}),
        Parties.find({showLocation: false}, {fields: fieldsWithoutLocation})
        ];
});
```

But how can I do this elegantly with a few conditional fields when publishing multiple items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) based on Michel Floyds "subscribe to them all!" solution, return multiple cursors from a publish like this:

```
return [
    Identities.find(query, options),
    Identities.find(merge(query, {showLocation: true}), {fields: {location: 1}}),
    Identities.find(merge(query, {showGuests: true}), {fields: {guests: 1}}),
];
```

2) Add a third field called "publicX" and fill/empty that field whenever the item with "showX" is edited/created, then include
this field in the field specifier instead of the true "X" field.
This solution is the only one that works if you also want to sort or filter by these fields, that way you can use publicX instead of "X" in queries and field specifiers.

3) use an observation yourself and control the results more tightly:

```
Meteor.publish("activeParties", function () {
    var self = this;
    var query = {active: true};

    //Observe the collection query for acivity
    var handle = Parties.find(query).observeChanges({
        //Runs one time first on all matching documents and sends them to the client
        //also runs each time a document is added
        added: function (id, fields) {
            if(!fields.showLocation) { //User choose to hide field
                delete fields.location; //Remove field from document
            }
            //etc.. add as many more conditional fields here as wanted

            self.added("Parties", id, fields ); //Sends the new document to the client
        },
        //Runs each time a matching document was updated, getting the id and only the changed fields
        changed: function (id, fields) {
            if("showLocation" in fields) { //check if showLocation was updated
                if(!fields.showLocation) {
                    fields.location = undefined; //marks field for deletion on client
                } 
                else {
                    //Needed because "fields" only contains the changed fields, so we need to pull the actual value from the DB
                    //You should probably test here that the doc still exist first
                    fields.location = Parties.findOne({_id: id}, {location: 1}).location;
                }
            }
            //etc.. add as many more conditional fields here as wanted

            self.changed("Parties", id, fields ); //Sends the changes to the client
        },
        //Runs each time a document is removed
        removed: function (id) {
            self.removed("Parties", id );
        },
    });
    self.ready(); //Tell the client that all the data was published

    //Runs when the client unsubscribes from this publish
    self.onStop(function () {
        //Stops observing the collection
        //important because otherwise it would continue observing even after unsubscribing
        handle.stop();
    });
});
```

This solution may be "low level" but it's very flexible and can be adapted to different needs, even complex conditions involving many fields and it's all on the server side so no private data is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Define a `transform` function when you [create your collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)
2. Use [cursor.map()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map) on the server to run a callback on every document and include/exclude fields based on your requirements. The resulting object is an array instead of a cursor but the client will happily use that.
3. Use [cursor.fetch()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) on the server side and then process the resulting array with a `forEach()`

Comment: How will using cursor.map() and cursor.fetch() affect reactiveness?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know the answer off the top of my head. An array is not reactive but otoh you're going to do this on the server side anyway in a publish function. The `transform` approach would definitely be reactive.

Comment: After a bit of testing, the "transform" function only runs on the client, so technically the private data is published, which is not so good. also, returning cursor.map() and cursor.fetch() in publish throws an exception "Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors". apparently you can't publish an array of documents, only a cursors array.

Comment: You'd have to return the array from a Meteor.call() then but that's hardly the same as a publish. Darn good question actually.

Comment: Dug around SO for awhile only to find that (a) there's no way to convert an array to a cursor, and (b) if you use `cursor.map` on the server in a method call then it's up to you to refresh it from time to time so you lose reactivity. It might be that your own solution is the elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reflection, your original idea was on the right track but here's a slightly different (and possibly more meteoric) way to think of the problem.

Create a publication for each set and subscribe to them all!

```
Meteor.publish('partiesWithLocations',function(){
  ... unique logic for this publication
  return Parties.find({showLocation: true}, {fields: fieldsWithLocation});
});

Meteor.publish('partiesWithoutLocations',function(){
  ... unique logic for this publication
  return Parties.find({showLocation: false}, {fields: fieldsWithoutLocation});
});
```

The nice thing is that *even if your logic results in overlapping publications* you'll still get the right set of data back in the client.

Comment: I like your approach but would you consider editing your answer to make it in one publication that returns multiple cursors,  one cursor with all the normal fields, and an extra one for each conditional field that only pulls that one field on that one condition?